# Problem with using string as object value in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have code like this
In one file I have

```js
interface NominativeCaseType {
    corn: string;
    buckwheat: string;
    rice: string;
    barley: string;
    wheat: string;
}

export const nominativeCase: NominativeCaseType = { // this is Називний Відмінок in Ukrainian language
    corn: 'Кукурудза',
    buckwheat: 'Гречка',
    rice: 'Рис',
    barley: 'Ячмінь',
    wheat: 'Пшениця',
}
```

in another file I have

```
import { nominativeCase } from '../../linguistics/categoriesNames';

export const MainScreen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('corn');
    return (
        <article>
            {nominativeCase[category]}
        </article>
    )
}
```

and problem is that typescript dont allows me to use `{nominativeCase[category]}`. VsCode says

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'NominativeCaseType'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'NominativeCaseType'.ts(7053)

I tryied to google it, but still dont understand how what does it means and how to fix it.
I even find solution like this [Typescript error: TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833469/typescript-error-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type)
And I change my code to

```
interface NominativeCaseType {
    [key: string]: string;
    corn: string;
    buckwheat: string;
    rice: string;
    barley: string;
    wheat: string;
}
```

But I still dont understand what does this error means and what `[key: string]: string;` means 
Help me please

Comment: Pls read the docs: indexed types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Comment: I believe this answer will help you to understand the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063502/how-to-iterate-through-an-object-in-typescipt-a-proper-way/67063966#67063966\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the cleanest way to handle this is to specifically narrow the type of `category` to `keyof NormativeCaseType`. What that does is restrict the values to strings that are the property names.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState<keyof NominativeCaseType>('corn');
```

The problem then is that you may need to narrow other incoming strings from callbacks or other untyped sources when you call `setCategory`.

```
const x: string = 'buckwheat';
setCategory(x as keyof NominativeCaseType);
```

**Edit:** `[key: string]: string;` is for defining a "catch-all" for properties that are not explicitly defined. You really don't want that here unless the object is really free-form and essentially "untyped" other than that the properties are all string values.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean how to solve current typescript error.
You propose how to rewrite current logic, but there are even another logic. I just croppped code to show main.

Comment: @АндрійГрушецький `const [category, setCategory] = useState<keyof NominativeCaseType>('corn');` should do the job. Please keep in mind, if code provided in your example is cropped, then it is on your side to make it right.

Comment: @АндрійГрушецький No, this is exactly how to solve the current typescript error and is not a "logic" change but a type change. I've added an edit to explain the `[key: string]: string;` and why it may not be what you want.